# why i can't print my datas of object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here are my codes:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '1',
  database : 'test'
});
connection.connect();

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/html');
});

app.get('/index/:name',function(req, res){
    data = connection.query('SELECT * FROM deneme', function(err, rows, fields){
        if(err) throw err;
        veri = rows;
        return veri;
    });

    res.render('index', {
        title: req.params.name,
        data: data
    });
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Shortly I want to print my datas of mysql

```
INSERT INTO `deneme` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'yusuf'),
(2, 'ali');
```

When I call localhost:8080/index/yusuf it shows below:

```
[object Object]
```

What can i print datas?

**EDIT**

My index.jade file:

> !!! 5 html   head
>       title= title   body   p= data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a string representation, you could use `JSON.stringify(myObject)`.

### Edit:

```
res.render('index', {
    title: req.params.name,
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
});
```

But I'm not sure if that's what you want. You probably want to access the data's properties by referencing them:  `#{data.someProperty}`.

Or you could make the data object return a string representation when it's printed. [Here is an example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString).

Comment: How can i use this when i'm using jade engine?

Comment: I have updated my questions. please look jade file. What i need to edit? I can't understand to using #{data.someProperty} sorry.